Format \paragraph titles
after many attempts, I can't do this in LaTeX (XeLaTeX or Pdf Latex):
\paragraph{} vs \paragraph{toto}
I want 1/ continuous paragraph numbering 2/ a symbol after the title IF it's non-empty :
\paragraph{} A short story.

A short story.

\pragraph{toto} A short story.

TOTO. --- A short story.

Any ideas?
Thank you,
--Fred
Not minimal, not working example :
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, A4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Include paragraph numbering

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\theparagraph}{.5em}{}[.~---~]

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{} Blablabla

\paragraph{Title of paragraph} Blablabla

\end{document}


Please extend to a full minimal example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that so we have a better understanding of what exactly you are doing, which class and packages you are using.

As @daleif says, this is very class/package dependant. I'm not sure, but just in case: are you aware that \paragraph is not actually intended to be used for paragraphs but would be better named \subsubsubsection? So if you are trying to number paragraphs (rather than \paragraphs), do clarify that.

Thanks for this. I have added a minimal example. \paragraph could be \subsubsubsections I guess, but \paragraph seems to work as well. My question could be the same with subsections with or without title.

There is no \subsubsubsection. I meant it would be clearer if \paragraph were called that. Thanks for adding the example. The fact you're using titlesec is crucial. I avoid it, though, so I'll leave others to answer.

\paragraph is a 4th level section heading so should be used after \subsubsection   just as \subsection should be used after \section.

@DavidCarlisle It's not OK to skip levels?

@cfr it's perhaps OK if you know that's what you are doing but most people doing this assume \paragraph is related to paragraphs (what gave them that idea:-) but even if you "decide" to skip levels it will cause problems if you switch to a class that increases secnumdepth or if you turn on accessibility pdf tagging and the section heirarchy is confused or ...

@DavidCarlisle That's inconvenient. Well, not the secnumdepth bit - that's OK. But accessibility tagging. Not that I use it ... yet.

@cfr well it's fixable of course but naturally the the default setup assumes a fourth level heading macro should be tagged as a 4th level heading.

@DavidCarlisle Oh, well that's different. Most of my documents are using non-standard sectioning anyway. Or, rather, a mix of standard and non-standard. So I wouldn't expect tagging to work out-of-the-box. I wouldn't expect it to cope with multiple ToCs either.

@cfr yes but that means you don't count:-) everything in tex is changeable so any statement about "some command \foo does something", may not apply if you have redefined \foo to do something else. It's still a good rule to state though if it covers the 99% of people using the standard definition.

@DavidCarlisle I wasn't suggesting you shouldn't say it. And I can count, I think. And occasionally do. Sometimes even in English.

I'd define a command for the job. You can abuse \paragraph for this, but it's much better if you mark up your document in an independent way.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\counterwithout*{paragraph}{subsubsection}% continuous numbering
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Include paragraph numbering

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\theparagraph.\@}
  {.5em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}

\NewDocumentCommand{\No}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\paragraph{}}{\paragraph{#1.\@\hspace{0.5em}---}\ignorespaces}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test A}

\No Blablabla

\No[Title of paragraph] Blablabla

% the trick here is to get two chapters on the same page
\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Test A}\endgroup
%%% end trick

\No Blablabla

\No[Title of paragraph] Blablabla

\end{document}


If you don't want continuous numbering, just remove the \counterwithout line.
